# Error message: Premature end of script headers 

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

This was working but all the sudden I'm getting this error message. "Error message:
Premature end of script headers: cust.php"

```
<?php
    //contact to database
    $user = '';
$pass = '';
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="cust"; // Table name

// Create a connection to the MySql server
$conn = mysql_connect('', $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


//Get data in local variable
 $v_Fname=$_POST['First_Name'];
 $v_Lname=$_POST['Last_Name'];
 $v_FAdd=$_POST['First_Add_Line'];
 $v_postCode=$_POST['Postcode'];
 $v_Num=$_POST['ContactNum'];
 $v_Email=$_POST['Email'];


// check for null values
if ($v_Fname==""  or $v_Lname=="" or $v_FAdd==""  or $v_postCode==""  or $v_Num=="" or         $v_Email=="")
echo "All fields must be entered, hit back button and re-enter information";
else{
$query="INSERT INTO       $tbl_name(First_Name,Last_Name,First_Add_Line,Postcode,ContactNum,Email) values('$v_Fname','$v_Lname','$v_FAdd','$v_postCode','$v_Num','$v_Email')";
mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
echo "You have registered as a Customer, Thank you";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Please help, Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @eggyal I just had a lecture about SQL injection an hour ago, how funny. but security is not really a problem.

Comment: That's always what you say until you get hacked ;) Except if the application if only for your own personnal use, always be careful about security...

Comment: @adrien just little project I'm working on, it will never be published :)

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to include the hostname, user and pass for your database in the question either..

Comment: @WillDemaine cheers, forget to edit before posting.

Comment: Check its admins then. Usually this error is caused by problems in the network layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this

```
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$conn)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Also you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for each post variables.

Thanks.

Comment: try applying spaces like $query="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (

Comment: There is no reason to quote a variable name. `"$foo" == $foo`, so use `mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn)`